# creating a link - jquery slider

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

Hope someone can help.

Firstly please see - http://designbyaltitude.com/ii/

I have created a content slider using jquery however I want to link the "Click here to read more. " to the about page but can seem to work out how to do it.

Basically I want it to jump to the about us section when click here is pressed

Comment: We need a little more context.  What do you mean by slider?  What have you tried?  What should happen when you click **Click here...**

Comment: UUUmmmm, I dont understand your question well...

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear - I want it to jump to the about us section when click here is pressed

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the cycle plugin you are using doesn't expose an easy way to go to a specific image.  But, since you've got the nav that already works, you can just trigger a click on the appropriate link.

```
jQuery("#menu li a:eq(1)").trigger("click");
```

**Edit:** To bind a click handler to your link you'll need a way to select it.  Best would be to give it a class like `aboutUsLink`.  This way, if you ever want to create another link to the about us page, you don't need to change any script - just give the new link the same class and both will get the click handler.  If you give your link a class of `aboutUsLink`, you can put the following code in the `<head>`.  It causes the about us page to be shown when any element with a class of `aboutUsLink` is clicked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery(".aboutUsLink").click(function () {
            jQuery("#menu li a:eq(1)").trigger("click");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Stupid question but where do I put that?

Comment: @Miles - That code should run when the link is clicked... I'll update my answer to be more specific.